# Setting up third party libraries for UIMA AS application

Tags: classpath, setup-deployment, uima

I have an UIMA AS application that is using third party libraries. I would like to know the following:
1. Where (location) we can add these third  libraries such that the deployed application to be aware of them and not throwing "ClassNotFoundException"?
   A brute force solution for me, was to add them directly in the UIMA AS "lib/" folder, but this solution was just for testing and is not acceptable in production.
2. How can be set up this third party libraries when generating PEAR file in a such a way that deploying the application will consider them and won't be necessary to manually add them to the classpath?

I'll look forward for your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question: my approach was 
1. Create a lib folder for the third library
2. create a script that adds to the UIMACLASSPATH the lib folder

@set UIMA_CLASSPATH=%UIMA_CLASSPATH%;../../lib;../../bin
call deployAsyncService.cmd 
for the second question:
 I use the maven plugin for generating the pear file.

Excerpt from the pom.xml (maven related)

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <!-- Copy the dependencies to the lib folder for the PEAR to 
          copy -->
        <execution>
          <id>copy-dependencies</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/lib</outputDirectory>
            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.uima</groupId>
      <artifactId>PearPackagingMavenPlugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>

      <!-- if version is omitted, then -->
      <!-- version is inherited from parent's pluginManagement section -->
      <!-- otherwise, include a version element here -->

      <!-- says to load Maven extensions (such as packaging and type 
        handlers) from this plugin -->
      <extensions>true</extensions>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <configuration>
            <classpath>
              <!-- PEAR file component classpath settings -->
              $main_root/lib/*.jar
            </classpath>

            <mainComponentDesc>
              <!-- PEAR file main component descriptor -->
            </mainComponentDesc>

            <componentId>
              <!-- PEAR file component ID -->
              ${project.artifactId}
            </componentId>

            <datapath>
              <!-- PEAR file UIMA datapath settings -->
              $main_root/
            </datapath>

          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>package</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <!-- Clean the libraries after packaging -->
        <execution>
          <id>CleanLib</id>
          <phase>clean</phase>
          <configuration>
            <tasks>
              <delete quiet="false" failOnError="false">
                <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib" includes="**/*.jar" />
              </delete>
            </tasks>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the compiled classes from your external jars and pack them into your UIMA component jar. As for the PEAR file, you might find that a similar approach works (unpack the pear, add the .class files, repack)